# Suspend while in background [C, SDL2]

Tags: c, cpu, rendering

I'm following [lazyfoo's tutorial on SDL](http://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/index.php) and have adapted the code in Lesson 03 a number of ways, but the adaptation of main concern is `while(SDL_PollEvent(&e)!=0)` to `if(SDL_WaitEvent(&e))`. Originally, I decided to used SDL_Delay() to throttle the CPU, but ultimately decided SDL_WaitEvent() in an If statement was best. As you can imagine, the CPU usage is much better. Thinking ahead, I thought about situations in which SDL_PollEvent() would be useful and realized that some kind of timer should be used with SDL_PollEvent() such as to throttle the FPS.

The following code is in my main thread. While `if(SDL_WaitEvent(&e))` significantly reduced the CPU usage, it's not perfect. Particularly, comparing Firefox on my system to this application: Firefox was using 0.2% CPU while this application used around 4.4%. How could this be?

```
while( !quit ) {                        // Keep running until quit
    if( SDL_WaitEvent( &e ) ) {         // Suspend until event received
        switch( e.type ) {              // Switch on event types
            case SDL_QUIT:              // User requests quit
                printf( "Shutting down...\n" );
                quit = true;
                break;
        }
    }

    SDL_BlitSurface( gXOut, NULL, gScreenSurface, NULL );   // Apply image to surface
    SDL_UpdateWindowSurface( gWindow );                     // Update the surface           
}
```

After fiddling with Firefox and this application while monitoring the Activity Monitor (Mac OS X), I found that Firefox immediately picked up CPU once it was active. This is perfectly fine because when Firefox is the active application, the user isn't paying attention to other applications.

However, my application insists on a 4-6% CPU. Why? I think it has to do with the `while(!quit)` loop. This loop is always active, whether in the foreground or background. So, my question to all of you fabulous people is this: How can I suspend a particular loop, thread, or even entire application once the application is in the background and then resurrect it once it returns to the foreground? [View code paste here](http://codebin.org/view/9eb9707e). The bitmap used in code can be found on lazy foo's tutorial, or you can make your own 640 x 480 bitmap so long as it's referenced correctly in the code. Refer to `const char* BMPimage = "x.bmp"` at the top of the file.

Comment: I found that adding the following code to the switch statement greatly improved performance: `default:SDL_EventState(e.type,SDL_IGNORE);break;`. Even without the `SDL_EventState(e.type,SDL_IGNORE);` statement, the CPU usage was greatly improved. However, `SDL_EventState(e.type,SDL_IGNORE);` allows other events not specified in cases are set to be ignored. Just be sure to re-enable them if they're needed. This also works with `while(SDL_PollEvent(&e)!=0)`, which is useful for OpenGL updates. However, this doesn't answer my question of task suspension when the window is not active.